# How to use CompareString function so it works on both Windows XP and Windows 7

Tags: winapi, windows-7, string-comparison, windows-xp-sp3

I have an application built on Windows 7 SP1 Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

It seems `CompareString` doesn't work the same way on Windows 7 and Windows XP. I am creating an  `EndsWith`/`StartsWith`-like (See C# `String.EndsWith`) methods, but where it works on Windows 7 as expected, but not on Windows XP.

Here are my `StartsWith` and `EndsWith`:

```
bool String::StartsWith( const String& value, bool bCaseSensitive ) const
{
    if(this->strLen == 0 || value.strLen == 0)
        return false;

    DWORD flags;
    if(bCaseSensitive == false)
        flags = LINGUISTIC_IGNORECASE;
    else
        flags = NORM_LINGUISTIC_CASING;

    if( CSTR_EQUAL == CompareStringW(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, flags, this->_str, static_cast<int>(value.strLen), value._str, static_cast<int>(value.strLen)) )
        return true;
    else if(CSTR_EQUAL == CompareStringW(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, flags, this->_str, static_cast<int>(value.strLen), value._str, static_cast<int>(value.strLen)))
        return true;
    else if(CSTR_EQUAL == CompareStringW(GetThreadLocale(), flags, this->_str, static_cast<int>(value.strLen), value._str, static_cast<int>(value.strLen)))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

---

```
bool String::EndsWith( const String& value, bool bCaseSensitive ) const
{
    if(this->strLen == 0 || value.strLen == 0)
        return false;

    DWORD flags;
    if(bCaseSensitive == false)
        flags = LINGUISTIC_IGNORECASE;
    else
        flags = NORM_LINGUISTIC_CASING;

    size_t maxLen;
    if(this->strLen < value.strLen)
        maxLen = this->strLen;
    else
        maxLen = value.strLen;

    LPCWSTR szStartOffset;

    if(maxLen == this->strLen)
        szStartOffset = this->_str;
    else
        szStartOffset = (this->_str + (this->strLen - value.strLen));

    if( CSTR_EQUAL == CompareStringW(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, flags, szStartOffset, static_cast<int>(maxLen), value._str, static_cast<int>(maxLen)) )
        return true;
    else if(CSTR_EQUAL == CompareStringW(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, flags, szStartOffset, static_cast<int>(maxLen), value._str, static_cast<int>(maxLen)))
        return true;
    else if(CSTR_EQUAL == CompareStringW(GetThreadLocale(), flags, szStartOffset, static_cast<int>(maxLen), value._str, static_cast<int>(maxLen)))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

If somebody could help me I'd be very grateful.

Comment: What exactly does not work ? What does it do on XP and what do you expect it to do ? Did you try to debug the code ?

Comment: I'm running the XP machine in VirtualBox, and I havent been able to figure out how to remotely debug it, see; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418955/how-to-remote-debug-a-windows-xp-process-from-visual-studio-2010-windows-not-s

Answer (score 1):

So there was a combination of things.

First, CompareString returns 0 on error, and as you can see, I do not check for that. On Windows XP, it did fail, and GetLastError() set to 1004 = "Invalid flags.". The error is the clue to the next issue.

Second, I am always using one flag or another other, and on Windows XP, NORM_LINGUISTIC_CASING causes the 1004 error. And since the default behavior of this function is case sensitive, this flag is not really needed **most of the time**, and flags can be set to 0.

I have created a demonstration program that implements StartsWith: **stringtest.cpp**

```
// cl /MTd /DUNICODE /D_UNICODE_ stringtest.cpp
// MTd  - statically compile libcrt to binary, this way you don't have to copy msvcrtd100.dll etc to the XP machine.

#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdio>

int StartsWith(LCID locale, const WCHAR* szOrg, const WCHAR* szValue, bool sensitive, bool expected /* Can be used for asserts. */)
{
    int retval(0)
    DWORD flags = sensitive ? 0 : NORM_IGNORECASE; // You could replace 0 with NORM_LINGUISTIC_CASING to make it fail on Windows XP.

    int cchValue = lstrlenW(szValue);

    // if szOrg can't hold szValue, it doesn't start with szValue.
    if( cchValue > lstrlenW(szOrg) )
        return CSTR_LESS_THAN;

    // We trick CompareString to think szOrg is the same length as szValue.
    // This is how we check only the cchValue first characters of szOrg.
    retval = CompareStringW(locale, flags, szOrg, cchValue, szValue, cchValue);

    // You could assert on retval and parameter 'expected '.

    return(retval);
}

// Some compiler magic..
#define SHOWBOOL(expr)  { \
                            int ret = expr; \
                            DWORD gle=GetLastError(); /* Cache GLE in case printf changes it. */ \
                            printf( "%s = %s\r\n", ( ret == CSTR_EQUAL ? "true" : "false"), #expr ); \
                            printf("GetLastError() = %d - ret = %d\r\n\r\n", gle, ret); \
                        }

// Named this way since we get the expression to console, easier to read.
bool ExpectsTrue = true;
bool ExpectsFalse = false;

bool Sensitive = true;
bool Insensitive = false;

int main(int argc, WCHAR* argv[])
{
    SHOWBOOL( StartsWith(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, L"Hello World", L"Hello", Sensitive, ExpectsTrue) );
    SHOWBOOL( StartsWith(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, L"Hello World", L"hello", Sensitive, ExpectsFalse) );
    SHOWBOOL( StartsWith(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, L"Hello World", L"hello", Insensitive, ExpectsFalse) );
    SHOWBOOL( StartsWith(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, L"Hello World", L"1Hello", Sensitive, ExpectsFalse) );

    SHOWBOOL( StartsWith(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, L"Hello World", L"Hello", Sensitive, ExpectsTrue) );
    SHOWBOOL( StartsWith(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, L"Hello World", L"hello", Sensitive, ExpectsFalse) );
    SHOWBOOL( StartsWith(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, L"Hello World", L"hello", Insensitive, ExpectsFalse) );
    SHOWBOOL( StartsWith(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, L"Hello World", L"1Hello", Sensitive, ExpectsFalse) );

    SHOWBOOL( StartsWith(GetThreadLocale(), L"Hello World", L"Hello", Sensitive, ExpectsTrue) );
    SHOWBOOL( StartsWith(GetThreadLocale(), L"Hello World", L"hello", Sensitive, ExpectsFalse) );
    SHOWBOOL( StartsWith(GetThreadLocale(), L"Hello World", L"hello", Insensitive, ExpectsFalse) );
    SHOWBOOL( StartsWith(GetThreadLocale(), L"Hello World", L"1Hello", Sensitive, ExpectsFalse) );

    SHOWBOOL( StartsWith(GetSystemDefaultLCID(), L"Hello World", L"Hello", Sensitive, ExpectsTrue) );
    SHOWBOOL( StartsWith(GetSystemDefaultLCID(), L"Hello World", L"hello", Sensitive, ExpectsFalse) );
    SHOWBOOL( StartsWith(GetSystemDefaultLCID(), L"Hello World", L"hello", Insensitive, ExpectsFalse) );
    SHOWBOOL( StartsWith(GetSystemDefaultLCID(), L"Hello World", L"1Hello", Sensitive, ExpectsFalse) );

    return(NO_ERROR);
}
```